# How to create a new database in already existing postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I was trying to create a new database in my already existing postgres container.

But it is skipping the database initialization part.

I am getting this message after running the `docker-compose up` command: **"PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization"**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3'
    services:
        db:
           container_name: db
           environment:
               POSTGRES_DB=new_db_name
           volumes:
               - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        app:
           container_name: app
           depends_on:
               - db
```

I am providing new database name. So it should create a new database, right?

But it is not happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the already running postgresql and run this command

```
CREATE DATABASE newDbName;
```

You can find more details at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html

Comment: Yes, this is one way. I got the issue, it was related to volume. Since I was using the same volume it was not creating new DB.